# programs' title bar dissapear

Tags: window-manager, window-buttons

I have the next problem:
the programs' title bar just dissapear and I can't move the windows, maximize, etc.
It occurs when I turn on the computer, but not always. 
Is it a bug or something??

---

I've searched and I found that the command `metacity -replace` worked for my problem
anyone knows why it happened.
I have compiz but I had it dissabled when it happened.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a bug: specifically, a window-manager crash.  You can check the `.xsession-errors` file in your home directory for any pertinent error messages.

On the other hand, gnome-session is supposed to restart the window manager should it crash, and I'm not sure why that's not happening here.

Do you use Desktop Effects?  Perhaps compiz is still running, and it was gtk-window-decorator that crashed?

Comment: Ok, I should check .xsession-errors.
Yes, I use compiz

Answer (score 4):

if you use compiz you can try `gtk-window-decorator –replace`

Comment: This worked for me. I got into this problem after trying to increase the width of Chromium browser too much (two workspaces). Not it got reverted.